# Serializing an F# function

Tags: f#, functional-programming, json.net

Using F# I've some configuration that I want to serialize to disk using Newtonsoft.Json. The config data is a record type. One of the fields in the record type is a function of type string->bool and is used to compare a string to a given value. e.g.

```
(fun (x:string) -> x = "1")
```

Serializing the type succeeds but the field isn't successfully stored (it is recorded as '{}') and therefore deserializing fails. This seems to be by design.

How do I store a function so that it can be used to populate the record type from disk when deserialized and still be executable?

I've looked at quotations as a means of storing expressions as data but I'm not sure if this is the way to go. If it is then I'm struggling to get this working.

How can achieve what I need?

***Update;***

```
type Logic = string -> bool
```

The record type storing config;

```
type Exclusion = 
| FromDataValue of QItem * Logic * ExcludedItems
| FromDataValuesAnd of (QItem * Logic) seq * ExcludedItems          
| FromDataValuesOr of (QItem * Logic) seq seq * ExcludedItems
```

The Exclusion record is populated by a user and runs against some data sets excluding items from the return collection. The QItem represents a string in the dataset that the Logic function is applied to, and if returns true the items in ExcludedItems are excluded from the results.

Initially the config is created by a user within the solution so all works fine. However once a config is created I want to be able to save the config to disc so that it can be loaded and run again when required.

So I need to be able to store this, but I want to be able to store it as a string then run it again when loaded.

Comment: What would you expect the JSON representation of your function to look like?

Comment: What do you expect a serialized function to look like in JSON? Perhaps you should look for ways to *ignore* the field during serialization?

Comment: Add the `JsonIgnore` attribute to the property. BTW it would help if you actually posted your code

Comment: I edited my answer to include an example of using a quotation to store the actual function logic in JSON.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can serialize a function to JSON and then deserialize it and execute the function later using [FSPickler](https://mbraceproject.github.io/FsPickler/):

```
open MBrace.FsPickler
open MBrace.FsPickler.Json
open System.IO
open System.Text

let serializer = JsonSerializer(indent = true)
let utf8 = UTF8Encoding(false)

let toJson (x: 'a) =
    use stream = new MemoryStream()
    serializer.Serialize(stream, x)
    stream.ToArray() |> utf8.GetString

let parseJson<'a> json =
    use reader = new StringReader(json)
    serializer.Deserialize<'a>(reader)

let f = fun x -> x + 1

let serialized = toJson f

let deserialized = parseJson<int -> int> serialized

deserialized 1 // returns 2
```

The serialized JSON for the function looks like this:

```
{
  "FsPickler": "4.0.0",
  "type": "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]",
  "value": {
    "_flags": "subtype",
    "subtype": {
      "Case": "NamedType",
      "Name": "FSI_0002+serialized@23",
      "Assembly": {
        "Name": "FSI-ASSEMBLY",
        "Version": "0.0.0.0",
        "Culture": "neutral",
        "PublicKeyToken": ""
      }
    },
    "instance": {}
  }
}
```

Although `instance` is blank, it records the metadata about the anonymous type created for the function.  That way, it can invoke the correct code when you call the deserialized version, as long as the function type is available in the AppDomain where you do the deserialization.

**EDIT**

If you want to literally serialize the logic for the function, you can use FSPickler to serialize a code quotation instead:

```
open MBrace.FsPickler
open MBrace.FsPickler.Json
open FSharp.Quotations
open FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator
open System.IO
open System.Text

let serializer = JsonSerializer(indent = true)
let utf8 = UTF8Encoding(false)

let toJson (x: 'a) =
    use stream = new MemoryStream()
    serializer.Serialize(stream, x)
    stream.ToArray() |> utf8.GetString

let parseJson<'a> json =
    use reader = new StringReader(json)
    serializer.Deserialize<'a>(reader)

let f = <@ fun x -> x + 1 @>

let serialized = toJson f

let deserialized = parseJson<Expr<int -> int>> serialized

let increment = deserialized |> QuotationEvaluator.Evaluate

increment 1
```

This way, the quotation gets serialized to JSON with all the logic described as an expression tree, and when you deserialize it you can use the [FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FSharp.Quotations.Evaluator) library to turn it into a runnable function that you can invoke.

The JSON is now considerably larger, but this can be deserialized and evaluated anywhere:

```
{
  "FsPickler": "4.0.0",
  "type": "Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.FSharpExpr`1[Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[System.Int32,System.Int32]]",
  "value": {
    "attribs": [
      {
        "attribs": [],
        "term": {
          "Case": "CombTerm",
          "Item1": {
            "Case": "NewTupleOp",
            "Item": {
              "Case": "GenericTypeInstance",
              "GenericDefinition": {
                "Case": "NamedType",
                "Name": "System.Tuple`2",
                "Assembly": {
                  "Name": "mscorlib",
                  "Version": "4.0.0.0",
                  "Culture": "neutral",
                  "PublicKeyToken": "b77a5c561934e089"
                }
              },
              "TypeArgs": [
                {
                  "Case": "NamedType",
                  "Name": "System.String",
                  "Assembly": {
                    "_flags": "cached",
                    "id": 9
                  }
                },
                {
                  "Case": "GenericTypeInstance",
                  "GenericDefinition": {
                    "Case": "NamedType",
                    "Name": "System.Tuple`5",
                    "Assembly": {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 9
                    }
                  },
                  "TypeArgs": [
                    {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 11
                    },
                    {
                      "Case": "NamedType",
                      "Name": "System.Int32",
                      "Assembly": {
                        "_flags": "cached",
                        "id": 9
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 15
                    },
                    {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 15
                    },
                    {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 15
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "Item2": [
            {
              "attribs": {
                "_flags": "cached",
                "id": 4
              },
              "term": {
                "Case": "CombTerm",
                "Item1": {
                  "Case": "ValueOp",
                  "Item1": {
                    "_flags": "subtype",
                    "subtype": {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 11
                    },
                    "instance": "DebugRange"
                  },
                  "Item2": {
                    "_flags": "cached",
                    "id": 11
                  },
                  "Item3": null
                },
                "Item2": {
                  "_flags": "cached",
                  "id": 4
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "attribs": {
                "_flags": "cached",
                "id": 4
              },
              "term": {
                "Case": "CombTerm",
                "Item1": {
                  "Case": "NewTupleOp",
                  "Item": {
                    "_flags": "cached",
                    "id": 12
                  }
                },
                "Item2": [
                  {
                    "attribs": {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    "term": {
                      "Case": "CombTerm",
                      "Item1": {
                        "Case": "ValueOp",
                        "Item1": {
                          "_flags": "subtype",
                          "subtype": {
                            "_flags": "cached",
                            "id": 11
                          },
                          "instance": "C:\\Users\\aeshbach\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\~vs220A.fsx"
                        },
                        "Item2": {
                          "_flags": "cached",
                          "id": 11
                        },
                        "Item3": null
                      },
                      "Item2": {
                        "_flags": "cached",
                        "id": 4
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "attribs": {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    "term": {
                      "Case": "CombTerm",
                      "Item1": {
                        "Case": "ValueOp",
                        "Item1": {
                          "_flags": "subtype",
                          "subtype": {
                            "_flags": "cached",
                            "id": 15
                          },
                          "instance": 32
                        },
                        "Item2": {
                          "_flags": "cached",
                          "id": 15
                        },
                        "Item3": null
                      },
                      "Item2": {
                        "_flags": "cached",
                        "id": 4
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "attribs": {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    "term": {
                      "Case": "CombTerm",
                      "Item1": {
                        "Case": "ValueOp",
                        "Item1": {
                          "_flags": "subtype",
                          "subtype": {
                            "_flags": "cached",
                            "id": 15
                          },
                          "instance": 11
                        },
                        "Item2": {
                          "_flags": "cached",
                          "id": 15
                        },
                        "Item3": null
                      },
                      "Item2": {
                        "_flags": "cached",
                        "id": 4
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "attribs": {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    "term": {
                      "Case": "CombTerm",
                      "Item1": {
                        "Case": "ValueOp",
                        "Item1": {
                          "_flags": "subtype",
                          "subtype": {
                            "_flags": "cached",
                            "id": 15
                          },
                          "instance": 32
                        },
                        "Item2": {
                          "_flags": "cached",
                          "id": 15
                        },
                        "Item3": null
                      },
                      "Item2": {
                        "_flags": "cached",
                        "id": 4
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "attribs": {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    "term": {
                      "Case": "CombTerm",
                      "Item1": {
                        "Case": "ValueOp",
                        "Item1": {
                          "_flags": "subtype",
                          "subtype": {
                            "_flags": "cached",
                            "id": 15
                          },
                          "instance": 25
                        },
                        "Item2": {
                          "_flags": "cached",
                          "id": 15
                        },
                        "Item3": null
                      },
                      "Item2": {
                        "_flags": "cached",
                        "id": 4
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "term": {
      "Case": "LambdaTerm",
      "Item1": {
        "isMutable104": false,
        "name": "x",
        "stamp": 0,
        "typ": {
          "_flags": "cached",
          "id": 15
        }
      },
      "Item2": {
        "attribs": {
          "_flags": "cached",
          "id": 4
        },
        "term": {
          "Case": "CombTerm",
          "Item1": {
            "Case": "StaticMethodCallOp",
            "Item": {
              "Case": "GenericMethodInstance",
              "GenericDefinition": {
                "Case": "Method",
                "Signature": "T3 op_Addition[T1,T2,T3](T1,T2)",
                "IsStatic": true,
                "DeclaringType": {
                  "Case": "NamedType",
                  "Name": "Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators",
                  "Assembly": {
                    "Name": "FSharp.Core",
                    "Version": "4.4.1.0",
                    "Culture": "neutral",
                    "PublicKeyToken": "b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
                  }
                },
                "ReflectedType": null
              },
              "TypeArgs": [
                {
                  "_flags": "cached",
                  "id": 15
                },
                {
                  "_flags": "cached",
                  "id": 15
                },
                {
                  "_flags": "cached",
                  "id": 15
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "Item2": [
            {
              "attribs": {
                "_flags": "cached",
                "id": 4
              },
              "term": {
                "Case": "VarTerm",
                "Item": {
                  "_flags": "cached",
                  "id": 40
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "attribs": {
                "_flags": "cached",
                "id": 4
              },
              "term": {
                "Case": "CombTerm",
                "Item1": {
                  "Case": "ValueOp",
                  "Item1": {
                    "_flags": "subtype",
                    "subtype": {
                      "_flags": "cached",
                      "id": 15
                    },
                    "instance": 1
                  },
                  "Item2": {
                    "_flags": "cached",
                    "id": 15
                  },
                  "Item3": null
                },
                "Item2": {
                  "_flags": "cached",
                  "id": 4
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't expect this to work... That's fascinating but also kind of scary.

Comment: @Jwosty I actually use this technique (serialized code quotations) in distributed computing to do distributed sequence processing (think `Array.Parallel.map`, but farming it out to multiple servers).  You can even have closures and it will serialize the relevant state automatically.

Comment: Huh... That's pure insanity... I _have_ to try this now!